# OnItemClick is not working

Tags: android

Here is my adapter class code

Here I was trying to click the list item and want to redirect to next activity with respect to the item clicked.

But OnItemCLick is not working

```
public class AdvancedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public AdvancedAdapter()  {
        super();
    }

    public String getAttributeName(int position) {      
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new String("User Profile");
        case 1:
            return new String("Reset Energy Expended");
        case 2:
            return new String("Reset Pedometer");
        case 3:
            return new String("Organizing Data Tiles");
        case 4:
            return new String("Cloud Upload Period");
        case 5:
            return new String("Auto Reconnect");
        case 6:
            return new String("Watches");
        case 7:
            return new String("Notes");
        case 8:
            return new String("Module Controls");
        case 9:
            return new String("Sencor Module Info");
        case 10:
            return new String("Expert Settings");
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getAttributeValue(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:


        case 1:forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        case 2:forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        case 3:forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:

        break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 11;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get already available view or create new if necessary
        FieldReferences fields;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.advanced_list_item, null,false);
            fields = new FieldReferences();
            fields.Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.advanced_list_item_text);
            fields.Button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.advanced_list_item_button);
            convertView.setTag(fields);
        } else {
            fields = (FieldReferences) convertView.getTag();
        }           

         // set proper values into the view
        /*String value = getAttributeValue(position);*/
        String name = getAttributeName(position);

        fields.Name.setText(name);


        return convertView;
    }

    private class FieldReferences {
        TextView Name;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Button Button;
    }
}
```

and my onitemclick code

```
AdvancedList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg2==0){
                System.out.println("enterd enterd");
                Intent i=new Intent(AdvancedActivity.this,DemographicsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }

    });
```

when trying to click on list item 
OnItemclick is not working

Comment: post your `advanced_list_item.xml` file

Comment: can you please try to remove button from advanced_list_item.xml and only use textview now check and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

for this problem, simply replace code in onitemclick listener by code,

```
            System.out.println("enterd enterd");
            Intent i=new Intent(AdvancedActivity.this,DemographicsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your list's item view you are having a Button view and that's taking focus before the whole list item can take on click.

So you just need to add an attribute in the root layout element of your list item's layout ie.

in root element of your layout/advanced_list_item file.xml

***android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
```

something like above

Now your both listview's onItemClickListener as well as your button's onClickListener will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a whole day on same problem I realized that the best way is to add 
`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"` 
in all the TextView and adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  in the root VieGroup.